# NCSS count doesn't change

Tags: java, pmd

[image: the code with the pmd warning]

I'm getting the error that I have 29 ncss line count, but after adding comments it doesn't remove it in pmd. Why is that, do I need to add more comments?

Comment: Can you also include the code via text? It will be easier for others to read.

Answer (score 1):

`NCSS` means the number of non-comment lines - almost equivalent to the number of statements (number of semicolons) in your method.
It does not mean how many lines have not been commented, and if you add comments, it won't decrease.

Your actual number of executable statements in the method will remain the same, even if you add a comment to each and every statement.

Divide your large method into smaller methods to reduce NCSS.

Comment: In your case, the main problem is the lot of cases in the switch. If the CaseType and TileType have mostly the same names, you can just use something like `TileType tileType = TileType.valueOf(entry.getValue().getCaseType().name())`

Comment: Only for the DEFAULT case, you may have to take `TileType.UNKNOWN` statically, other than that, it seems all the others have the same name for both.

Comment: Have a separate method `private TileType getTileTypeFromCaseType(CaseType ct)` that does this conversion and also handles UNKNOWN. This will reduce NCSS.

Comment: For the definition, how PMD is calculating NCSS, see the javadoc https://docs.pmd-code.org/apidocs/pmd-java/7.0.0-rc2/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/metrics/JavaMetrics.html#NCSS